# PrimeReact Dropdown asynchronous data options

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I'm using the Dropdown in PrimeReact, but seems like it doesn't support to continuously fetch data options from server, I would like to perform something like `<Dropdown onFilter={filterWithServer} />`

Is there any way to do like that?

Comment: Hmm, seems pretty straightforward and supported by Prime. Can you post a little bit more information on what you're doing and what error is being thrown (if there is an error?)

Comment: And can you correct your tags?

Comment: Follow this docs: https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/dropdown,  the `primereact`give 2 props relate to what I said is `filter` and `filterBy`, but they give no option to customize what thing should be done in the filter function. I think they only support the static data filtering.